# Excel Cannot Close Word When Stepping Through Code (F8)

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, ms-word

When running the following code from `Excel`, it does what I expect it to do:
It opens `Word`, raises an error which gets handled via `CleanError` and closes `Word` via `CleanExit`.

```
Sub testWord()

    ' VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Word 1?.0 Object Library
    Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
    ' 'Open' Word.
    wdApp.Visible = False
    ' To prevent Word from staying open if an error occurs.
    On Error GoTo CleanError

    ' Raise an error.
    Err.Raise 13

CleanExit:
    ' Close Word.
    wdApp.Quit

Exit Sub

CleanError:
    MsgBox "Run-time Error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume CleanExit

End Sub
```

When stepping through the code using <kbd>F8</kbd>, `Excel` hangs (is still `running` the code) i.e. doesn't close `Word` after `wdApp.Quit`. When closing `Word` via `Task Manager`, the line `Exit Sub` is highlighted and stepping further is 'allowed' again.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Is that the complete Code?

Comment: @Yes, that is the complete code. What ever you put instead of `Error.Raise 13` to raise an error should be irrelevant. It only hangs when stepping through.

Comment: Hmm, code is working for me in both ways. I can step through with F8 it and I can run it with F5. Sorry, no idea, why it is not working at your side. Maybe you should change `wdApp.Visible = False` to `wdApp.Visible = True` just to see what is going on in Word.

Comment: Do you have a Watch set on wdApp in the Watches window?  That may be the problem (at least, I saw that behaviour only with a Watch set...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a Watch set on `wdApp` in the Watches window, or something along those lines.

I only see that behavior with a Watch set on wdApp.

Comment: I didn't see that one coming. Mystery solved. I'm glad the code is correct. Removing the watch or reopening the workbook solve the issue.

Comment: I thought at first it was the "As New", which is sometimes a problem.  Took a bit of trial and error to find the Watch issue.